# Complex objects passed as args/kwargs between class based views in Django

Tags: python, django, django-formtools

I currently have a SessionWizardView from formtools package implemented.

```
class DataframeFormView(SessionWizardView):
    def done(self,form_list):
       params={}
        for form in form_list:
            params.update(form.cleaned_data)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('download',kwargs={'params':params}))
```

Everything is working fine in the forms view, and when the forms are successfully filled the above mentioned function runs, however I need to pass the params argument to another view:

```
from django_downloadview import VirtualDownloadView, VirtualFile
class DataframeDownloadView(VirtualDownloadView):
    def get_file(self):
         ### Access params dictionary here!!!!

        return VirtualFile(tfile.name, name=tfile.name)
```

Thing I've tried:

1) override `__init__` to add `self.params = kwargs.pop('params')`

2) create method to access to kwargs specific key params using `return self.kwargs['params']`

3) Mixin solution (probably badly implemented but I thing there are constraints in these two CBVs)

Ultimately, suing method 1 and 2, I manage to access merely to a string representation of the params dictionary through reversing to download/url/. I need a more programatically solution to obtain the original dict object. TLDR: How can I pass complex objects between views.

Best regards,

Comment: If you need to keep a significant amount of state around between page loads, you might consider using the session rather than trying to pass it around in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by kungphu, probably the best way to share complex objects between views is using the view session.
For future reference, I end up doing the following:

```
def done(self,form_list,**kwargs):
    params={}
    for form in form_list:
        params.update(form.cleaned_data)
    self.request.session['params']=params
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(self.download_url_name))
```

and I also changed the session serializer to pickle.